# Strange crash after switching to version 25.2.0 of the support library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I noticed after switching to version 25.2.0 of the support library that some of my users started to experience this crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.support.v4.e.a.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.getInEpicenterView(FragmentTransition.java:817)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.access$000$97c744e(FragmentTransition.java:37)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition$4.run(FragmentTransition.java:657)
       at android.support.v4.app.OneShotPreDrawListener.onPreDraw(OneShotPreDrawListener.java:64)
       at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1073)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5903)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:828)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:588)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:558)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:814)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
```

I looked around online but didn't find anything meaningful. Has anyone else been able to reproduce this crash? Does anyone know any workarounds?

**Update**

I have found the method to reproduce the crash. My app is setup using a single Activity and multiple fragments. I have fragments A and B that both display a list of items. The items in each list are the same, just sorted differently and a different layout is used. Both of these fragments are "top level fragments", by which I mean they can be accessed from the nav drawer directly.

Fragment A is the designated "root fragment". That means that tapping back will always eventually return to fragment A. As such, fragment A is coded such that attempting to navigate to it from the nav drawer is done by popping off all items from the fragment back stack. This appears to be important to reproduce the crash.

Tapping on an item in fragment A or B will open fragment C and the item view is used as a shared element for a transition effect from fragment A or B to fragment C. I can reproduce this crash by tapping on an item in fragment B, then opening the navigation drawer and selecting fragment A.

I am now looking into what is causing this crash and what I can do to work around it.

**UPDATE 2**

I have pinpointed the exact code that produces this crash. Given fragments A and B, and a shared element transition from A -> B. The repro steps are as follows:

1. Push A to the back stack.
2. Navigate to B from A (shared element transition will play).
3. Pop everything off the back stack via `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, 0);`.
4. Observe the crash.

I have filed a bug with Google as it appears to be a support library bug. I am still accepting answers if anyone has any workarounds.

Comment: Can you update your post to include your code?

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: @Drew unfortunately I actually have no idea how to reproduce this issue and thus I have no idea what code to include. I was hoping that others might have experienced the same thing and can share what cause this error for them.

Comment: @fillobotto yes. However I am assuming that the obfuscated code is not my own doing as you can see that the rest of the stack trace is NOT obfuscated. I could be wrong though.

Comment: The problem comes from shared elements. Does this fragment have shared elements?

Comment: Ah interesting. I do use shared elements in one place in the app and I admit I use it pretty unconventionally. I am using shared elements from one fragment to another CHILD fragment in another fragment. I will be testing that specifically now but thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Was having this issue too. I temporarily just locked the nav drawer when the user was on a screen that used shared elements as a quick fix. But it looks fixed in support libs 25.3.0